# Javascript: Tell if window.opener is acceptable without triggering an error.

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, window.opener

As the title suggests, I need to be able to tell if a window was opened by my application or by some other application. In the first case, I can invoke javascript functions on the opener, in the second, I get a cross origin error.

Is there a way to tell before I actually try and get an error, or is the only way to do this is to wrap the call to window.opener in try catch?

Thanks

Comment: if you pass a name to `window.open()`, that string will be reachable within the new tab at `window.name`. if there is no name, or it's not the one you set, it's from another app.

Comment: That would work. Thank you.